# how draw much number in a lineChart javafx?

Tags: javafx, linechart, waveform

hello I created this code to display an audio wave form, I can not view them in graphic Linechart because there are a lot of number. Can you help me?The following is my code...

```
  // take a file from table (item selected) ; call extractWaveForm and take point that I want to plot; draw linechart
    public void plotAudio() throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, WavFileException {
        if(Table1.getSelectionModel()!= null){
         extractedData = extractWaveform(files.get(Table1.getSelectionModel().getFocusedIndex()));      
         XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
         series.setName("My Data");
         for(int i =0; i<extractedData.length; i++){
              series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(extractedData[i],RATE));
         }
         lineChart.getData().add(series);
        }

    }    
    // call extract to WaveFormExtract class that extract the point.
    public double[] extractWaveform(File file) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
            return new WavFileExtractor().extract(file);
      }
```